# Check the square elements of another array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have created a programme that checks if the 2nd array is square of the 1st array or not. In the programme, I used a square variable double and sorted elements and check with the target that both were the same or not; if they were the same, it returned true. But what is the missing part? Could you please check and rectify that?

```js
function compareSqr(nums, target) {
  let square = nums.map((num) => num * num).sort((a, b) => (a - b));
  if (square == target) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
console.log(compareSqr([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16]))
```

Comment: Arrays are compared by _identity_, and you have two _separate_ array objects. `square==target` will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare two object, but if they do not share the same object reference then you get different objects.

Better compare the array with their values.

```js
function compareSqr(values, squares) {
    return values.every((value, index) => value ** 2 === squares[index]);
}

console.log(compareSqr([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16]));
```

Comment: Perhaps post in the dupe and vote to close as dupe